# How do I get two panels to share a parent's width in Devexpress

Tags: c#, user-interface, devexpress

This sounds simple to me but I'm not sure if there's a best/suggested way to do it.
I'd like my UI to have a panel docked along the top, split into two panels, left and right, that always share the width of the parent equally. There'll be a minimum overall width so nothing gets squashed, but on resizing I'd like the two panels' widths to always be equal.

I thought of using a split container control but it doesn't do what I want in this case as I can't disable manual resizing.
My current idea is just to override the `onResize` method (forgot the exact name), and just manually set the two widths to parent.width/2, but it seems a bit roundabout, and potentially slow if it's calling `onResize` for every pixel's worth of movement.

Is there a better way to do this, or a control/layout that handles this for me?

**Disclaimer:** I'm using an older version of DevExpress, 10.1.4. It's not my decision and I don't think I can get the team to upgrade at the moment. Using C# on .Net platform 3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would drop a couple of panels onto the form and set their Size within the form's ResizeEnd event handler.  This looks to be the best solution from my point of view.

Comment: The ResizeEnd event sounds like what I need, thanks. Watch out, I'm going to ask another (more difficult) devexpress question in a minute! :)

Comment: Would you mind having a look at this question as well? Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369852/devexpress-how-do-i-base-a-gridcontrols-data-on-the-sorted-filtered-data-from

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XtraLayoutControl to achieve this, but that might be overkill.

Otherwise, you'd have to do it manually.