# Devexpress - How do I base a Gridcontrol's data on the sorted/filtered data from another GridControl?

Tags: c#, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have two GridControls on my form. One is a fairly large dataset, including a column named Score.  I want my other GridControl to show a subset of this (e.g. Top 3 and Bottom 3 based on the values of Score).

How can I best accomplish this? If it were the same GridControl I imagine I could just use a different view, but since it's completely separate, should I just grab a copy of the view, filter/sort the data and display it as a new dataset? Or is there a way to link my second GridControl's data to my first's?

**edit:** I could do `grid2.datasource = grid1.datasource` and go from there. There won't be any dynamic updates to the table so maybe this is the way to go?

Comment: So basically you want to show filtered values in the other grid?

Comment: yes. I can figure out a few different ways to do it, I just don't know if Devexpress provides a built-in way to do this efficiently.

Comment: yes it has build in filter mechanism. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the following approach:

1) create a new DataView, filter it based on your approach and set the second gridControl's DataSource to this DataView;

OR

2) set the DataSource property of the second GridControl to the same value and filter the corresponding GridView.

Answer (score 1):

No need to create a new DataView. Check out the gridview's CustomRowFilter event.

Use `e.ListSourceRow` to get the row in the datatable.

So if suppose you want rows with value > 25 to be displayed and the rest hidden

```
gridView_CustomRowFilter(object sender, RowFilterEventArgs e)
{
      if(dataset.datatable[e.ListSourceRow]["ColumnName"] < 25)
      {  
          e.visible = false;
          e.handled = true;
      }
}
```

Comment: Would this work across the two grid controls? Could I point `dataset.datatable` to my original grid's datasource and have the filtering done on the fly in the second?

Comment: Would work against 'n' grid controls. This has nothing to do with the underlying datasource. You can have 'n' grids bound to the same datasource. Each GridControl has its own gridView. So each gridview can filter rows independently.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So in essence, this is similar to the suggestion of binding the 2nd grid to the same datasource and doing the filtering independently. I'll try both suggested approaches and mark the one I use, but they're both good to know!